# Dynamic font size in QTextEdit

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, qtextedit

I have a document in HTML format. The fonts are specified in 'pt' units (e.g 14pt).
I also have page width specification (e.g 400pt), so when the text line is longer than 400, it will wrap to the next line.

I would like the appeared font size in QTextEdit to match the window widget size. Such that if I make the window smaller, the fonts will get smaller. If i make the window bigger, the appeared fonts will get bigger. In any case, the line will break at the exact same place. 
Similar to the editing experience in Pages or Word.

What is the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: I know you mention `QTextEdit` but does the text actually have to be editable or is this purely a viewer?

Comment: it has be be editable